# Plotting Classification data with separate marker for each classifier in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I have a vector as a data with zeros and ones in it:

```
y = [0;1;0;1;1;1;1;;0;0;0;0;0]
```

I want to plot it against some X values so that the training example with 'y=0' has a marker of 'o' and that with 'y=1' has a marker of '+'. How can I do that in octave? I am new to octave and therefore can't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Plot zeros and ones separately with desired markers. Use `logical` to get logical indices of `y`.

```
x = 1:12;
y = [0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];
logind = logical(y);
plot(x(logind),y(logind),'+', ...
    x(~logind), y(~logind),'o');
axis([-1 13 -0.2 1.2]);
```

[image]